# What is the rule for second cousin in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I needed to do second cousin regarding donald ducks family tree. I only managed to get cousin's rules only

```
cousin(X,Y):- uncle(Unc,X), father(Unc,Y)
```

Comment: What did you try, what are the "base predicates" that you can use?

Comment: How would you define second cousin? Think about how it can be expressed with the predicates you have (including, now, `cousin/2`).